Analyze the variational problem corresponding to the functional $\int_0^1 y(x) y'(x) \mathrm{d}x$
Consider this problem

Analyze the variational problem corresponding to the functional
$$
J(y) = \int_0^1  y(x) y'(x) \mathrm{d}x\qquad y(0) = 0, \text{ }  y(1)=1.
$$

If the Euler-Lagrange's equation is used, we get $0=0$. What does this mean?
However, by using integration by parts,
\begin{align}
J(y) &= (y(x)(y(x) +c))\big|_{0}^1 - \int_0^1 (y(x)+c)y'(x)\mathrm{d}x \\
     &= 1+c - J(y) -c(1-0) \\
     &= 1-J(y)
\end{align}
for some constant $c$.
Thus $J(y) = \frac{1}{2}$. This means $J$ is constant.
Therefore, every point of its domain is a global and local extremum (minimum and maximum).
Is this solution correct?

Yes, $J$ is constantly equal to $1/2$. Another way to prove this is by subtitution; the integrand is the derivative of $\frac{y(x)^2}{2}$.

If we have $L(y,y',x) = F(y(x))y'(x)$, $J(y) = \int_a^b L(y,y',x) dx$ and $y(a), y(b)$ given, then
$$
J(y) = \mathscr{F}(y(b))-\mathscr{F}(y(a))= C_0
$$
hence
$$
\delta J(y) = \delta C_0 = 0
$$
